# How to send an error message if the user did not tag a member

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot using discord.py.
The command is - **]kill** 
What I want to do is ,
If the user did not tag a person I want to send

> Please Tag Someone

This is my code-

```
@bot.command(name='kill')
async def kill (ctx,person:discord.Member) :
  author = ctx.author
  person: discord.Member
  embed = discord.Embed (color=discord.Color.red())
  embed.set_author(name=f'{author} kills {person.display_name}')
  embed.set_image(url = (random.choice(killgifs)))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an error handler for that or create a custom one.

I personally would use the `on_command_error` handler but we now create a custom one.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command(name='kill')
async def kill(ctx, person: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author} kills {person.display_name}')
    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(killgifs)))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@kill.error # Error handler for the kill command
async def kill_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument): # Check which error occurs
        await ctx.send("Your message!") # Send your message
```