# doesn't send Message when member doesn't show up as an user

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(name='kick')
async def kick(ctx, message, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason is None:
        reason = " no reason provided"
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} has been kicked. \n Reason: {reason}')

    if member is False:
        await message.channel.send("User can't be found")
```

This is my code. I have tried multiple different ways to do this but none of them have worked. The kick command works which is what I wanted but when I try to kick someone that the bot doesn't recognize it never says that the user can't be found. I'm confused as to why this is, and I would like some help, please. Thanks. :) Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Comment: At what times would member evaluate to being False? Wouldn’t it rather be None?

Comment: To be honest, the reason I put it that way is that I was thinking if the argument isn't true then wouldn't it be evaluated as False. But you have a good point. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for those who are looking at this question and need help. Please note that I used part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433695/how-to-send-an-error-message-if-the-user-did-not-tag-a-member?rq=1)'s answer to find the answer to this question. Here's the code:

```
@bot.command(name='kick')`
async def kick(ctx, message, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason is None:
        reason = " no reason provided"
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} has been kicked. \n Reason: {reason}')


@kick.error  # Error handler for the kick command
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):  # Check which error occurs
        await ctx.send("User not found.")  # Send your message`
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me with this question. Sorry if this question was confusing for those who came across this. This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so I'm not really the best with asking questions on this platform at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

```
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  if reason is None:
    await member.send(member.name +f" has been kicked by {ctx.author}")
    await ctx.send(f"user {member} has been kicked by {ctx.author}")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
  else:
    await member.send(member.name +f" has been kicked by {ctx.author}, because:" + str(reason))
    await ctx.send(f"user {member} has been kicked by {ctx.author} because" + str(reason))
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

try this

Comment: Hey. I appreciate the effort to help me with this but it didn't work. Thanks for trying though. :)

Comment: but it is working for me

Comment: Well. That's weird. I don't know why it didn't work. :/